# Error while trying to configure VLAN with Open vSwitch

Tags: virtual-machines, switch, vlan

I am trying to connect a number of VMs using Open vSwitch. The VMs are on two separate physical boxes. Here is what I did:

1. Created two tap devices on one physical host 
   `sudo ip tuntap add mode tap tap0` and same for `tap1`
2. Bring them up 
   `sudo ip link set tap0 up`
3. Add them as ports to Open vSwitch 
    (`br0` was created as a OVS bridge previously)
   `sudo ovs-vsctl add-port br0 tap0 tag=1`

Now I booted the VMs (using VirtualBox) and assigned addresses `192.168.122.11` and `192.168.122.12`. Now when I try to ping one VM from another, I get the error `Connect: network is unreachable`. Since both VMs are connected to the switch on the same VLAN, I expect to be able to ping one from another. What is going wrong here?

**Update**
I found that the routing table goes blank after some time and that is when ping fails. If I add a static route, it works for some time and fails again. Any idea why does the routing table is erased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with DHCP configuration on the guests. Once I removed that, it worked fine.